# content security policy for HTML5 page with Social Plugins and API calls

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-domain-policy, content-security-policy

What [content security policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) is recommended to use for an HTML5 page with the following:

1) Facebook plugins

2) Twitter plugins

3) Google Plus One

4) Google Translate

6) from cdn.mywebsite.com

7) YouTube

I get many errors like the following:

```
The frame requesting access set 'document.domain' to 'facebook.com', but the frame being accessed did not. Both must set 'document.domain' to the same value to allow access.
```

I am using YouTube video iframes and many social widgets, including Pinterest API and others. Need your help.